# Why partitioned table in innodb doesn't support foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I tried to add a Foreign Key for a partitioned table in `MySQL` and I got the following error:

> ERROR 1506 (HY000): Foreign keys are not yet supported in conjunction with partitioning.

Why does `InnoDB` partitioning not support Foreign Keys? Is there a workaround?

Comment: There are some technical issues (related to partitioning splitting indexes up). It would not be completely impossible to implement (see the "yet"), it's more in the sense of `time + money + possible complications - fun >> current problem + usefulness`. As a workaround, you can create your own constraint by using a trigger, see e.g. [MyISAM Engine table relations (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23985617) (MyISAM also doesn't support foreign keys).